# Commits simply not showing on GitHub graphic?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

So since I started working on this new project, my commits stopped showing up on GitHub graphic, no green tiles for me. I worked on a personal project and I was able to see my commits on the graphic, but when it comes to the other project, nothing happens.

I already read the documentation and found nothing, my friends from work are not experiencing the same problem with the repository, so I don't know what else could be. I even deleted the project from my machine and cloned again, still nothing changes.

Yes, I can see my commits with `git log`, they're all there.

Comment: Is the repository public? Graph are only available on public repository.

Comment: No, it's private. But I do have the option to choose between showing private contributions or public, or both. It's available above the graphic on "Contribution settings".

Comment: But if the repository is private, you can only need the graph about commits, if you have GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud or GitHub Enterprise Server.

Comment: Are your commits on the default branch of the repository?

Comment: @GoodDeeds No, they're on another branch. 
main => develop => the-branch-im-working. But this shouldn't be a problem, right? I always worked like this and my commits were always on the graphic. I know it's a silly problem, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention that your commits are on a different branch other than the default branch. From [GitHub's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#contributions-that-are-counted):

> **Commits**
>
> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet **all** of
> the following conditions:
>
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made:
>
>   - In the repository's default branch
>   - In the `gh-pages` branch (for repositories with project sites)
>
> For more information on project sites, see "[About GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites)."
>
> In addition, **at least one** of the following must be true:
>
> - You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization that owns the repository.
> - You have forked the repository.
> - You have opened a pull request or issue in the repository.
> - You have starred the repository.

So, only commits from your default branch or a `gh-pages` branch will appear in the graph. If you are working on a different branch, and later merge to the default branch, all the commits you merged will then be visible on the contribution graph as well.